# We need different string to translate for scaled view count on the question page

Tags: bug, localization, views

View count with scale (i.e. kilo-view) on the question page (at the top of) needs a different string to translate. [Example on ruSO](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/468496/176217):

> [image: 13k раза]

It seems that current translation rely on non-scaled value (i.e. displayed in tooltip).

Check existing strings for [view count on list](https://ru.traducir.win/filters?sourceRegex=%5C%24%20views) vs [view count on question page](https://ru.traducir.win/filters?sourceRegex=Viewed%20%5C%24).

Comment: Does this only apply to view counts? Surely reputation and a few other things are also abbreviated with `k`.

Comment: @SebastianSimon I don't see any other issue with scaled values currently. BTW there're no extra words (than `k`) on scaled reputation count.

Comment: Not yet, but with how much reputation some of the users are getting, I wouldn't be surprised if M gets implemented within a few years.